# Probability density of joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let the joint density of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ is given by

$f(x,y)=1,$ where $ 0\le x,y \le 1$

Find, $P(X >2Y)$

***What I tried:-***

$P(X >2Y)=1- P(X <2Y)=1-[\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2y} f(x,y) dx dy]=1-[\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2y} 1 dx dy]$

I am getting the answer $0$

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and draw the area $x>2y$, you will see that you get the boundaries $2y< x <1$ and $0<y<\frac{1}{2}$, so you will get
$$P(X >2Y)=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{2y}^{1} f(x,y) dx dy=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}1-2y\,dy=\frac{1}{4}.$$

---

Remark: If you look at the drawing, you will see that it's easier to calculate $P(X >2Y)$ (area is one triangle) than $P(X <2Y)$ (area is a trapezium, which you will need to split into two separate integrals).

Comment: Yes I was also thinking so. If $x$ lies between $0$ and $1$, $y$ will lie between $0$ and $\frac{x}{2}$

Comment: I see the result would not be altered, but from a geometric point of view, and given that you are looking at the upper tail of the distribution with $P(X>2Y)$ shouldn't the integration limits be $\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{2y}^1f(x,y) dx dy$?

Comment: @justquestions You're right! I made a geometric mistake. Thanks for noting it. I will edit it immediately.